# Как лучше сделать анимацию нескольких монеток, которые уменьшаясь, летят в одну точку?

Tags: android

Есть изображение кучки золота, есть анимированный открывающийся сундук. При нажатии на кучку, она должна превратиться в горсть монеток и полететь в сундук. Каким образом лучше сделать анимацию этих монеток? Каждую загрузить как ImageView и отдельно анимировать?

Ответ на комментарий:

1. Я до сих пор новичок, и использую только ConstraintLayout, после уроков так повелось. Мне надо переделать все на Relative?
2. Мне не нужно наследовать ваш класс от AppCompatActivity, только провести нужные импорты?
3. Параметр **paddings** в **R.dimen.paddings** подсвечен красным.
4. Вот с этой строчкой запутался.
   **((тип parent startView)startView.getParent).removeView (startView);**

Изменил ее так:

**((ImageView)startView.getParent()).removeView(startView);**

но теперь removeView() красный.

5. При имплементации класса, мой главный класс требует обьявить абстрактным или имплементировать абстрактный метод AnimationEnd(int)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Использую для подобных целей (в моем случае - "летят" очки) класс ниже.

Использование: где надо для каждой кучки создавайте его экземпляр и передавайте контекст, `RelativeLayout` (да, надо чтобы корневой `View` `activity` был `RelativeLayout`. Можно `FrameLayout`), изображение, с которого начинается движение (ваша кучка, где бы она не была), изображение сундука (куда полетят деньги)), количество, которое "долетит" (сумма денег).

```
public class AnimateScore {
private static final int ANIMATION_DURATION = 400;

private View targetView;
private int offset, number;
private AnimationEnd animationEnd;
private ImageView img;
private RelativeLayout container;

interface AnimationEnd {
    void animationEnd(int number);
}

AnimateScore(Context ctx, RelativeLayout container, View startView, View targetView, int number) {
    animationEnd = (AnimationEnd) ctx;
    this.number = number;

    int dimens = (int) ctx.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.paddings);
    offset = (int) (-24 * ctx.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);

    this.container = container;

    this.targetView = targetView;

    img = new ImageView(ctx);
    int[] coords = {getRelativeLeft(startView), getRelativeTop(startView)};
    String str = "+" + String.valueOf(number);
    img.setImageResourse(R.drawable.my_img)
    img.setPadding(dimens, dimens, dimens, dimens);
    img.setX(coords[0] + dimens * 2);
    img.setY(coords[1]);

    ((тип parent startView)startView.getParent).removeView (startView);

    container.addView(img);
    img.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            drawAnimation(img);
        }
    }, 10);
}

private void drawAnimation(View v1) {
    v1.clearAnimation();
    ScaleAnimation animation = new ScaleAnimation (1, 0,1,0);
    animation.setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION + 100);
    animation.setFillAfter(true);
    v1.setAnimation(animation);
    v1.startAnimation(animation);
    v1.animate().translationX(getRelativeLeft(targetView))
            .translationY(getRelativeTop(targetView) + offset).setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION)
            .setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator()).setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            container.removeView(img);
            animationEnd.animationEnd(number);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

        }
    });

}

private int getRelativeLeft(View myView) {
    if (myView.getParent() == myView.getRootView())
        return myView.getLeft();
    else
        return myView.getLeft() + getRelativeLeft((View) myView.getParent());
}

private int getRelativeTop(View myView) {
    if (myView.getParent() == myView.getRootView())
        return myView.getTop();
    else
        return myView.getTop() + getRelativeTop((View) myView.getParent());
}
}
```

`offset` - для корректной работы (не знаю откуда смещение, но так)

`dimens*2` - чтобы учитывать два родительских `padding`

в классе-приёмнике не забудьте `implements AnimateScore.AnimationEnd`

немного адаптировал класс под ответ, если что-то не работает или есть вопрос - пишите в комментариях ;)

Раз:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/globalCont"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
     <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout...>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Два: нет, просто в нужный момент вызывайте экземпляр: `new AnimateScore (YourActivity.this, findViewById(R.id.globalcont),your_coin_pile_img,your_chest_img, 100)`

Три: это отступы, прописанные у меня в `dimen`. Это можно удалить либо подвести туда курсор, нажать alt+enter и ввести значение (обычно 5-10-15dp). Либо прописать в `dimen` в ручную.

Четвере: "тип parent" - тип контейнера в котором лежит ваша "кучка золота" (LinearLayout, FrameLayout, ConstrainLayout и т.д.)

Пять: имплементируйте :) (alt+enter, когда курсор на красном). Необязательная часть, можете удалить вместе с `interface`. Нужна, для того, чтобы отслеживать, когда анимация "дошла" и, например, только тогда добавлять монеты в сундук.

Comment: Благодарю! Сейчас напишу вопросы в отредактированном посте, а то тут неудобно.

Comment: @keltkelt, обновил ответ

Comment: Ругается на findViewById(R.id.globalcont), говорит что это View, а он ищет RelativeLayout.

Comment: Кажется приняло, когда я сперва сделал так RelativeLayout rel = findViewById(R.id.globalCont);  Странно, почему сразу не принимало.

Comment: Вылетает при попытке выполнить строчку, пишет что ресурс не найден. int dimens = (int) ctx.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.paddings);

Comment: Ресурс я добавил как вы сказали, он прописан.

Comment: Написал вручную dimens. Вроде бы работает, но сейчас такая проблема, что летит не к targetView, а в левый верхний угол экрана.

Comment: Т.е. У меня куча золота, а под ней сундук. В анимации одна монетка сначала скачет чуть вниз, а потом улетает в левый верхний угол.

Comment: @keltkelt, чтобы не скакала попробуйте убрать offset или dimens. И, возможно, в качестве targetView вы передаете не сундук, а что-то еще. Либо координаты вашего сундука занимают весь экран. Если вам надо движение только по одной оси (вниз), `translateX` тоже можно убрать.

Comment: Сделал явно v1.animate().translationY(700.0f). Кружок скачет вниз на эту координату, а потом также в левый верхний угол. По коду не могу понять почему он так делает. И еще там не много кружков, а один - так и должно быть?

Comment: не знаю насчет кружков. По идее их столько, сколько экземпляров (`new`) вы создаете. Чтобы он не "сбрасывался" в левый верхний угол, его нужно удалять ` container.removeView(img);` у вас прописано?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75959/discussion-between-keltkelt-and-jarvis-j).